# Typescript frontend and backend build with shared folder

Tags: typescript

I'm considering moving to typescript, but struggling with how to make a shared between frontend and backend folder?

I came up with this project structure:

```
frontend
- src
-- server.ts
-- functions
- dist
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- node_modules
backend
- src
-- client.ts
-- functions
- dist
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- node_modules
shared
- src
-- functions
---- doSmth.ts
-- index.ts
- dist
- tsconfig.json
```

Questions are:

1. What approach to use to get access from backend or frontend to shared functions and data? Should I use project reference and build first shared, then frontend or backend? Or should I somehow get a shared folder inside backend or front on their build?
2. Maybe there is a simple example of how to setup tsconfig.json so it's
   will work?

TypeScript documentation is confusing and didn't help much :(

All that i get now is a mess:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with two config files in your root folder, e.g. `tsconfig.client.json` and `tsconfig.server.json`, with different build rules. To compile, run one or both of

```
tsc --project tsconfig.client.json
tsc --project tsconfig.server.json
```

From [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) (relevant part highlighted):

> By invoking tsc with no input files and a --project (or just -p) command line option that specifies the path of a directory containing a tsconfig.json file, **or a path to a valid .json file containing the configurations**.

Comment: And what my dist will looks like? Where it will be?

Comment: Whereever you tell it to be in the `outFile` property of each respective config file.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using the [Nx workspace management](https://nx.dev/) tool as it is specifically build to solve this code-sharing issue. You can simply create a library within your repository that can then be imported everywhere (see: https://nx.dev/angular/tutorial/08-create-libs). It is even possible to conveniently boostrap the frontend and backend applications with popular frameworks like react, angular, nestjs and some more. You can keep your entire codebase (frontend + backend) inside one monorepo, which is a perfect setup for code sharing, dependency management and shared tooling. Nx let's you manage this TypeScript monorepo with ease and sets up a lot of the necessary infrastructure for you like linting, test automation and code-sharing. Me and my team are heavily relying on Nx now for over 6 months and could not imagine managing a TypeScript repository without it, give it a try! https://nx.dev

If using Nx is not an option for you, you can model the way the implemented code-sharing:

1. Create a new folder
2. Add an `index.ts` file which exports everything that should be accessible from outside the library
3. Add an entry inside your `tsconfig.json` -> `compilerOptions` -> `paths` that points to the `index.ts` of your library
4. Import the shared code via the import name you specified inside the `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Up-voting for sharing Nx which I didn't know!